# how to open view result from action call from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

i'm developing using ASP.Net mvc 4. I have a delete function in my Index view. Before user proceed to delete an item, this is the steps to go through

1. pop-up a confirm dialog to get the 'yes' or 'no' answer using javascript.
2. If the user say 'yes', I call the delete action from my controller
3. the delete action remove the item from database
4. the delete action return 'RedirectToAction ("Index");'
5. .. suppose the view will be updated with latest update

Step 5 is my problem.. its not working

Here is my code

The delete button

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteFile", new { id = @item.Id })"  
    onclick = "return confirm2delete(this);"
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete File">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
```

The javascript

```
function confirm2delete(obj)
{      
    deleteLinkObj = $(this);
    w2confirm("Are sure to delete this file ?")
    .yes(function () {
        $.get(obj.href, function (data) {
            alert(data); // i checked ..this return the html page created from the delete action
            window.open (data); // not the right approach ???
        });

    })
    .no(function () {
        alert("no");
        result = false;
    });
    return false;
}
```

The delete action in my controller

```
public ActionResult DeleteFile(int id)
{
    FileUpload f = db.FileUploads.Find(id);
    try
    {                
        FileInfo dfile = new FileInfo(f.fileUrl);
        if (dfile.Exists) { dfile.Delete(); }
        fileUrl = f.FileUrl.Replace("Images/Uploads", "Images/Thumbnails");
        FileInfo thumbnail= new FileInfo(fileUrl);
        if (thumbnail.Exists) { thumbnail.Delete(); }
        db.FileUploads.Remove(f);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  // or may i should return something else to make it work in javascript ???
}
```

Hope you guys can help me. I've been searching and trying for days to come to this level and I feel its time get some help. Just a little bit more. Almost there.

Comment: Firstly ajax calls stay on the same page so `return RedirectToAction("Index");` is pointless. The easiest way would be to return a json value indicating the item was successfully deleted, then just remove the corresponding item from the DOM.

Comment: You need to show the html for one of your rows to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls stay in the same page, so calling `return RedirectToAction("Index");` is pointless (it will not redirect). In any case it is unnecessary to return the new view. Instead you can just remove the existing elements from the DOM if the controller successfully deleted the item.  You have not shown your view, but assuming you have a table where a row might be something like

```
<tr>
  <td>the name of the file</td>
  <td>the delete link</td>
</td>
```

Then you can use the following where the 'delete' link is

```
<td><button type="button" class="delete" data-id="@item.Id">Delete</button></td>
```

The key points are the `class` and the `data-id` attributes - modify the rest to suit your display but remove the `onclick` attribute (stop polluting you markup with behavior and use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - its the 21st century!)

Then the script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteFile")';
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // modify if the containing element is not a <tr>
  w2confirm("Are sure to delete this file ?")
    .yes(function () {
      $.post(url, { id: id }, function(response) { // its a POST, not a GET!
        if (response) {
          row.remove(); // remove the row
        } else {
          // Oops, something went wrong
        }
      }).fail(function (response) {
        // Oops, something went wrong
      });
    })
    .no(function() {
      alert("no");
    });
});
```

Note if your using jquery version 1.9+ then the `else` block in the `$.post()` functuion is not required since `return Json(null);` in the method below will go to the `.fail()` callback

Then in the controller, return json to indicate the item was successfully deleted

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteFile(int id)
{
  FileUpload f = db.FileUploads.Find(id);
  try
  {                
    ....
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(true); // signal success
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return Json(null); // signal failure
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks... i follow your advice and it works but i have one more question .. what if i want to also send value from viewbag to the action, can i do like this  $.post(url, {id:id, val:ViewBag.val }, function(respond) { .. }

Comment: Not sure why you would need to add a `ViewBag` property (the controller sent that value to the view so the controller already knows what it was when you post, but yes you can. You will need to ask a new question and give a bit ode detail because the actual answer can vary depending on what the `ViewBag` property is.

Comment: ok .. for my second comment.. i got it.. we can send text as return.. so i can check if the return text == "SUCCESS" then remove the image from view else show the error message

Comment: And, yes you can return an error message. For example if successful - `return Json(new { success = true });` and if not successful - `return Json( new { message = "your message" });` Then modify the script to `if (response.success) { row.remove(); } else if (response.message) { alert(response.message) }`